# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'User' available as request attribute with root cause

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring , i am trying an example in spring MVC, but i am getting the mentioned error ,please check my code and help me  to resolve the issue.
    I tried in different URL mappings (like beanNameUrlMapping ,simpleUrlMapping ) but unable to resolve the issue, please let me know root cause for this issue and steps to resolve the issue

Thanks in Advance

**My code**

In this example i am just entering registration details in a jSP and want to show the details in once user details once registration is done.

My jsp page to enter the details
Register.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3 MVC Series - Contact Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form method="post" action="addContact.html" commandName="User"  >

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="firstname">First Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="lastname">Last Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="email">Email</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="telephone">Telephone</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="telephone" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Contact"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>    

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

In config file mapping the request to the controller 
    config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mys" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="userService" class="com.mys.services.UserServiceImpl" />

    <bean name="/addContact.html" class="com.mys.login.RegistrationController" 
    p:userService-ref="userService" p:formView="Register" p:successView="success" />

</beans>
```

My controller class

```
import com.formbean.User;
import com.mys.services.UserService;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class RegistrationController extends SimpleFormController {

    private UserService userService;

    public RegistrationController() {
        setCommandClass(User.class);
        setCommandName("user");
    }

    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws Exception {
        User user = (User) command;
        userService.add(user);
        return new ModelAndView("success", "user", user);
    }

}

Form bean  User.java

package com.formbean;

public class User {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String telephone;

    //setters , getter ()

}

package com.mys.services;

import com.formbean.User;

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Override
    public void add(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("user added successfully");
    }   
}
```

This is the issue i am getting

SEVERE: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'User' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'User' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.Register_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(Register_jsp.java:188)
    at org.apache.jsp.Register_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(Register_jsp.java:112)
    at org.apache.jsp.Register_jsp._jspService(Register_jsp.java:71)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Sep 4, 2013 11:52:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/MysteryShopping] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'User' available as request attribute] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'User' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)

Comment: Your command name is **user** (see your controller) not **User** (as specified in your `form:form` tag). Those should match.

Comment: Deinum, Thanks for your help. i have changed the setCommandName to User , even then i am facing the same issue please check my code and let me know whether i missed any mappings

Comment: Next to the fact that the names have to match you also have to make sure that you are passing through the dispatcherservlet for showing your JSP. Judging from the stack trace this isn't the case and you directly access the JSP.